# IWorkbenchListener preShutdown priority / order?

Tags: java, qt, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

So, I have this Eclipse RCP app that is managing some Qt resources behind the scenes via JNI. Qt vets will know that QApplication and Qt GUI objects do not take kindly to being constructed and destructed outside the main/GUI thread. QApplication construction using IStartup is not a problem, but QApplication destruction on shutdown is proving difficult. I am using IWorkbenchListener to clean up my Qt resources when preShutdown is called *on the GUI thread* as required by Qt. Problems arise when other IWorkbenchListeners veto shutdown *after* my preShutdown has been called. I need to prevent this situation.

Is there any way to force or ensure that my preShutdown is called last? Or are there any other novel ways to get some code executed *last* on the GUI thread just before it goes down?

Comment: why not cleanup in postShutdown, may be I am missing some of your requirement.

Comment: I really should have given that a shot before asking. I think postShutdown will do the trick. It is called after any vetoing could be done and by the all important GUI thread. I need to do more testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IWorkbenchListener.postShutdown() worked as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If your RCP implements `IApplication` you could add code after the `PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench` exits.

You could also try the `disposeExec` method of `Display`. The `Runnable` you pass that this method is called just before the display is disposed.

Comment: I bet that would work, unfortunately, I cannot edit that code.

Comment: Added Display.disposeExec

Comment: I am a bit wary of using Display in this particular situation, but that is a option. Thanks, I was not aware that such a method existed.